# How to use the bbPress import tool

Tags: bbpress, forum

I have used example.php to create a custom importer for Social Engine 3 to bbPress Forums but I don't seem to be having any success using it. What am I doing wrong? I enter server ip, name, port, username, and password but the import never gets past "Starting Conversion". When I select another platform's importer, I get errors saying there is no forum to import (which would be right because the table names/fields don't exist). What should I try?

My attempt at the custom importer is here: http://pastebin.com/Z0Zj7n0q

Edit: Firebug shows that starting conversion caused 500 Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://bbpress.org/forums/topic/social-engine-3-export-forums/#post-135964

This post has helped me greatly. Thanks Steven.